# why postman can not create rest instance but curl does ? (is there any way to do from postman only?)

Tags: marklogic

```
<error xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error">
    <status-code>500</status-code>
    <status>Internal Server Error</status>
    <message-code>REST-INVALIDREQUEST</message-code>
    <message>REST-INVALIDREQUEST: (rest:INVALIDREQUEST) Invalid request: Host does not match origin or inferred origin, or is otherwise untrusted.</message>
</error>
```

the above error message was sent from marklogic server to postman. Is there any other fix or way available to do same from postman. Kindly let me know!!

Comment: Looks like an XSS issue not a postman issue.

Comment: CSRF was applied to MarkLogic REST apis as a security measure, and there is currently no way around. There might be Chrome plugins that could bypass this, but you'd have to look for yourself i'm afraid.

Comment: Another option might be to put a transparent proxy in front of MarkLogic. Various ways to do that.

Comment: Note that this is not specific to just MarkLogic, other products with tight security suffer from this too..

Comment: @grtjn okay thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF was applied to MarkLogic REST apis as a security measure, and there is currently no way around. There might be Chrome plugins that could bypass this, but you'd have to look for yourself i'm afraid.

Another option might be to put a transparent proxy in front of MarkLogic. Various ways to do that.

Note that this is not specific to just MarkLogic, other products with tight security suffer from this too.

HTH!